# How does Perfectly Competitive Output Level Compare to Cournot Output Level

Tags: general-equilibrium, profit-maximization, perfect-competition, cournot

So Let there be two firms with Output Level x1 and x2 .Inverse Demand Function $P=a-bX $ where $ X=x1+x2 $.Both firms have same MC denoted by $c$. Is the Perfectly Competitive O/t > Cournot O/t level ?

Solving:
First finding the **Cournot o/t levels :**.

doing profit max of F1 & F2 and solving the equations and substituting in BR functions i get O/t levels as $x1=x2= \frac{a-c}{3b}$

Now finding **Perfect Competitive O/t Levels :**

I am stuck with P=MC and cant get ahead from here